# How to stop Windows 10 Mail app to create links/contacts from numbers?

Tags: html-email, number-formatting, windows-10-desktop

Windows 10 Mail app **converts some numbers to links/contacts automatically** in html emails.
Usually numbers or part of numbers with 000-s:

[image]

How can i stop this?
I've tried  with "text-decoration:none; text-transform:none;" but it didn't worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common, and occurs also in many mobile apps. What they are trying to do is be 'helpful' and convert them to phone numbers (typically).

To get rid of this, you can add an odd character that will break their find & replace: `&zwnj;` (zero-width non-joiner)

So in full:

```
Test number: 7 &zwnj;000 &zwnj;000 &zwnj;000 USD
```

You'll need to do this to break any combination of 6 or more numbers.

Comment: That's not a workable solution when the "links" are created in incoming emails. So frustrating.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th The question was relating to the creation of an email. For end users, try this: File > Options > Mail > Spelling and Autocorrect (button) > Autocorrect options (button) > Autoformat (tab) > and untick "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks"

Comment: I see nothing in the question that makes it specific to outgoing messages.  OP mentions some html attributes that he tried - but he may have been sending those test emails from a different account/application to his Window machine/app to test the behaviour of the Windows 10 Mail app.  Your comment above implies that the Windows 10 Mail app has a "file" menu - which, unless I'm mistaken, UWP apps don't have. I'm guessing that's an Outlook setting - but I don't have Office installed at the moment - so can't check.

Comment: Ah sorry yes I was talking there about Outlook and have just assumed that the app is basically the same. There may or may not be a setting like that, then.

Comment: No problem.  I haven't managed to find that setting in the default mail app - hence my frustration.  I had to (temporarily) switch to the web interface for Hotmail which, ironically, doesn't transform random numbers into links - just so I could copy a "reference number" to paste it elsewhere. smh.